# AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__' in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, kivy

I was just making a small project and made serval screens(using kivy) and in one screen where the user will enter his/her weight and height, I got an **Attributeerror** of ****getattr****. Don't know what's wrong I did in the code. I'm new to python so I need help.

**Here is python code:**

```
class UserHomeScrren(BoxLayout):
    

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(UserHomeScrren, self).__init__(**kwargs)
     

    def calculate(self):
        #weight =int(self.weight.text)
        weight=int(self.ids.backdrop.ids.backlayer.bmi_screen.weight.text)
        height= int (self.ids.backdrop.ids.backlayer.bmi_screen.height.text)
        print(self.ids.backlayer.ids.bmi_screen.ids.height)
        BMI = round((weight * 703) / (height ** 2))

        if BMI < 18.5:
            self.ids.results.text += "Your BMI is " + str(BMI) + " which means you are underweight."


    def clear(self):
        self.ids.results.text = ""
        self.ids.weight.text = ""
        self.ids.height.text = ""
        

        print(weight)
        print('calculate.....')


class ItemBackdropBackLayer(ThemableBehavior, BoxLayout):
    icon = StringProperty("android")
    text = StringProperty()
    selected_item = BooleanProperty(False)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):
            for item in self.parent.children:
                if item.selected_item:
                    item.selected_item = False
            self.selected_item = True
        return super().on_touch_down(touch)


class UserApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.title = "User Flana"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "DeepPurple"
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.size = (300, 550)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return super().__getattr__(attr)

    def build(self):
        return UserHomeScrren()

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    UserApp().run()
```

And here are the logs:

````
   File "d:\obacity\userHome\user.py", line 38, in calculate
     weight=int(self.ids.backdrop.ids.backlayer.bmi_screen.weight.text)
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 863, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'```
````

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you even need to redefine `__getattr__` again, right? :-)

Since you call `super()` in the `__init__` it should inherit the base class method of `__getattr__` which just returns the value for the attribute requested

Comment: Python gets the next method in the MRO whether `super()` is called or not. If a method is missing in the child class it checks the parent class, etc. automatically. The only thing `super()` is used for is if you want to call that specific parent classes method in addition to the child classes method.

Comment: if i remove `def __getattr__(self, attr):` function then it show the same error.